# Chromium stopped downloading files

Tags: chromium, downloads

Chromium stopped downloading files on one PC. It doesn't work whether it's pdf file from a website or photos from another. When I download from Firefox, it works. So I know that something broke on Chromium. when I go to the application download page, it's all blank. This page normally shows history of all your downloaded files.

What could have possibly broke? I'm a newbie that's why I don't know where to start digging. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update:

For chromium browser

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall chromium-browser
```

To clear the download history choose the clear all option at download tab. look at the image to eye it.

[image]

If problem still persists then disable all chrome extensions and try again.

hope that helps.